# Firefox does not accept ⌃⌘Space keyboard shortcut for Emoji & Symbols

Tags: macos, keyboard, firefox

I really love the option of **⌃⌘Space** to bring up Emoji & Symbols in macOS. Unfortunately this does not work in Firefox.

How can I get this to work?

I am on macOS Big Sur 11.3.1, and Firefox is the latest version.

Comment: Have you made sure Firefox is up to date? That shortcut works in Safari and in Firefox bringing up the same dialogue box for special characters. And I'm using Big Sur 11.5.1

Comment: yes, just updated it before posting the question

Comment: Given the downvoters, who as usual fail to help, I won't come back on this.

Answer (score 5):

It is a known issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1563862

However the issue is closed, and based on the comments it looks like it is related to the language of the browser.

As far as I can see the Firefox can be downloaded in different languages, but also language of the UI can be changed after. Also, it looks like if you are changing the language compared to the default the Emoji shortcut stops working.

So your best bet is to download Firefox in the language you are using it, instead of changing the language afterwards. Or you can always try to go to Preferences and change the language to the one Firefox was downloaded in originally. It may also matter to have the language of the System and Firefox set to the same.

In my case if I set Firefox to Italian the shortcut stops working, but if I set it to UK English, it starts to work (after restart). I assume it is because I've originally downloaded Firefox in English.

If you don't want to do that another workaround I've found is to go to `System Preferences… > Keyboard` and on the Keyboard tab turn on the "Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar". With this there will be a flag icon in the upper right of the screen, where the Emoji viewer can be opened, just like as if it were opened using the <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> shortcut. Bit more cumbersome...

Comment: But that is a dup of https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1563295 which says it has been fixed

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer above with more relevant information. After all it all comes down to the language of the Firefox UI.

Comment: I tested it on my version and it looks simply to depend on the chosen language in the Firefox preferences. If ( Firefox language == MacOS language ) then { shortcuts OK }.

Comment: Had the same problem (in 2022). I uninstalled it and reinstalled Firefox with brew cask and it worked.

Comment: The bug is back under Sonoma as https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1855346 — both ⌘+⌃+space and Fn+e seem to have quirks.

Comment: I has never really been fixed afaics, so it's not "back", it just still is.